# how to find the difference between sandbox and production in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, sandbox, production

Ihave some action thet if I try to do it in the sandbox it succeeded but when I tryed to do it in the production it failed
I'm looking for somethin thet can help find the difference between the two environments
tenks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too vague. Do you know how to capture debug logs and read them?

Could be many things - a validation rule or required field added in prod but not in sandbox. Could be a problem with some integration. Could be that the action silently calls something from a managed package and you don't have a license in production. Could be that the action checks your user's Role/Profile/permissions and something's missing. Could be some reference data missing. A flow/process builder that's deployed from sandbox but not activated.

There are some tools for comparing 2 environments (Gearset, OwnBackup...) or if you're a developer you could download the projects with sfdx/vscode and compare them with something like Winmerge.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know that about current environment you can query IsSandbox field from Organization object.

[select IsSandbox from Organization limit 1];

IsSandbox Indicates whether the current organization is a sandbox (true) or production (false) instance.

similarly you can use it in flows and other automation tools

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).